# non-kludgey left subscripts

Tags: subscripts

I was taught to make a left subscript as a right subscript to `{}`. For example, I would use

```
f: {}_RA \rightarrow {}_RB
```

to typeset this:

[image]

If you instead use

```
f: _RA \rightarrow _RB
```

the left subscripts end up in the wrong place (because LaTeX thinks they are right subscripts of the object before):

[image]

However, this trick doesn't work well with operators like `/otimes`. The code

```
A {}_\varphi\otimes_\psi B
```

puts too much spaace between the tensor product symbol and the subscript:

[image]

One solution I've found is to use spaces (including a negative thin space) to adjust the spacing. The code

```
A \; {}_\varphi \! \otimes_\psi B
```

produces this:

[image]

However, this is a kludge and doesn't communicate to LaTeX that `\varphi` should be attached to the `\otimes`. Also, the left subscript is still just a tad too far to the left. Does anyone know a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: There's the \sideset command for large operator symbols (like \sum), but it is specifically described as "unreliable" for ordinary symbols like \otimes.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but how do you get the underscores into the TeX snippets?  The MO workaround of backquoting the snippet doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @András Salamon: In "code mode" — not backquotes, but on a separate line starting with at least 4 spaces (or hit the "1001" button in the toolbar) — everything is printed exactly as you type.

Comment: Okay can delete comments now (by the way previously the comment was "Possible duplicate of X", but since SE made it "more friendly" I've been getting a few users comment to reply "yes" to such comments)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the [tensor](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=tensor) package. You can just issue

```
$A \tensor[_\varphi]{\otimes}{_\psi} B$
```

to get what you specified as an example. Note that if you have mixed upper and lower indices, the standard `\tensor` command will leave "phantom" spaces. To make all indices flush against the central symbol, use `\tensor*`.

Comment: (Oops; that comment was meant to be left on your comment to _my_ variant on this question!)

Answer (score 14):

The problem here is the special treatment of `\otimes` as a relational symbol, which adds space on either side of the symbol.  Put it in braces to suppress this behaviour:

`A {}_\varphi{\otimes}_\psi B`

The accepted answer, using `tensor`, does this implicitly.

For best spacing one should declare the decorated operation as a new mathematical symbol.
Instead of `\mathop` (suggested by François G. Dorais) which is used for large operators like `\prod` and `\sum`, `\mathbin` as used for `\otimes`, `+` and `\cap` might be suitable:

`A \mathbin{{}_\varphi{\otimes}_\psi} B`

Comment: Wrapping it all with \mathop produces the right spacing before and after the subscripts.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are a few packages that support this, such as [`leftidx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/leftidx/) and [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh/).

Comment: The second link doesn't work =(

Comment: leftidx works by putting a vphantom of the main glyph before the left super/subscript.  So it won't get the horizontal spacing right (note: I'm saying that without _actually_ testing it).

Comment: leftidx doesn't look like it addresses the spacing issue.