# Einstein summation convention

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

In Einstein's summation convention, it is sometimes necessary to have subscript and superscript indices in a certain order. If you just use `^` and `_`, these indices would appear on top of one another, e.g. `\Lambda^\mu_\nu`. How do I escape this?

---

(The following is an answer to the question, but I cannot add an answer as the question is closed.)

To escape this, you can type

```
\Lambda{}^\mu{}_\nu
```

The first `{}` is necessary to get the same *vertical* positioning for the first super-/subscript as for all the others.

Couldn't find this on the web, so I figured I'd post it myself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The package `tensor` should help.

Comment: This is almost, but not quite a question.  Could you maybe ask if there is an idiomatic way to do this in either Plain Tex or Latex?

Comment: My question was: How can you put super- and subscripts in order, rather than on top of one another? I couldn't find the answer on the web, but I found it by experimenting, and I decided it would be useful to put the answer on the web myself. So the answer is effectively in the posted question. Is this considered a problem?

Comment: Consider reopening.  He's trying to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_tensor#Changing_the_tensor_type

Comment: This question should be reopened, because the answer I'm giving above is useful and is not an answer to the "duplicate" question.

Comment: @dremodaris You should post your answer at [Is there a way to stop the vertical spread of multiple super- and sub-scripts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336/is-there-a-way-to-stop-the-vertical-spread-of-multiple-super-and-sub-scripts) I think. Basically `$x^2{}_6{}^4{}_8$` for the asked case.

Comment: @Archange The approach using curly braces is explicitly rejected in that question, because the OP there especially cares about the vertical positioning.

Comment: Yes, but I could not see a difference in vertical positioning with any of the symbols they mentioned (x X or Π).

Comment: I've posted an answer there. However, they ask a different question. Their question is about vertical positioning, whereas my question is about horizontal positioning and specifically the Einstein summation convention. They are obviously related, but they are not the same question. Please consider reopening.