# Left and right subscript / superscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I am trying to put two subscripts at the left and right of a character. For example, something like:  `_{t} p_{x}`  where p is in the middle. How do you do this?

Comment: @Alan: Why a comment?

Comment: @Caramdir It just seemed so short.  I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Since this is essentially about _left_ subscripts, you can also have a look at the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334/1235) (possible duplicate).

Comment: @Caramdir: The space has no effect in math mode ...

Comment: @JPi: Done.......

Comment: Very compliments for your question.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

There are many tools for scripts:

- For general math scripts before something, use `\prescript` provided by `mathtools`, for better alignment:

  `$ \prescript{14}{2}{\mathbf{C}} $`
- Alternatively, in order to have the left superscript indented to fit better with the shape of the symbol, use `\leftindex` from the `leftindex` package:

  `$ \leftindex^a_b {f}$`
  `$ \leftindex[I]^a_b {L} $`
- For large operators, use `\sideset` from `amsmath`:

  `$ \sideset{_a^b}{'}{\sum} A_n $`
- For tensors, use `tensor` package:

  `$ M\indices{^a_b^{cd}_e} $`
  `$ \tensor[^a_b^c_d]{M}{^a_b^c_d} $`
- For chemical equations, use `mhchem` package:

  `\ce{^{227}_{90}Th+}`

Please complete this list as you can.

The visual result:
[image]

Source code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mathtools,leftindex,tensor,mhchem}

\begin{document}

\verb!mathtools!:
$ \prescript{14}{2}{\mathbf{C}} $

\medskip

\verb!leftindex!:
$ \leftindex^a_b {f}$, $\leftindex[I]^a_b {L} $

\medskip

\verb!amsmath!:
$ \displaystyle \sideset{_a^b}{'}{\sum} A_n $

\medskip

\verb!tensor!:
$ \tensor[^a_b^c_d]{M}{^a_b^c_d} $,
$ M\indices{^a_b^{cd}_e} $

\medskip

\verb!mhchem!:
\ce{^{227}_{90}Th+}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I think that this is a great answer because it acknowledges the semantic element of LaTeX environments. Using `tensor` for, say, denoting an isotope is ontologically dodgy and its visual suitability is contingent on some hypothetical divergence of notation not occurring down the line.

Comment: I tried most of these and found the \tensor solution the best one.

Comment: Are there any options besides `mhchem` that don't require math mode? I'd like to typeset a downarrow before a letter in a phonetic transcription.

Comment: @RichardTerrett Worth mentioning that the difference is not _just_ of semantic adherence: ``\sideset`` will only work with math operators, not with any item.

Comment: Is there anything wrong (kerning?) with this simple approach? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317359/52160

Answer (score 86):

Are you doing this in math mode?

`${}_{t}p_{x}$`

should work.

Comment: Spaces are ignored in math mode. `$ _ t p _ x $` produces exactly the same effect.

Comment: @TH. I never realised that.  So whatever elicited the original question may have been lack of math mode altogether? I'll update the answer.

Comment: I would go for `{}_{t}p_{x}`, otherwise things like `\sum  _{t}p_{x}` give surprising results.

Comment: I think that the `t` and `x` are not aligned using this approach

Comment: @becko you'll need to match upper and lower i.e.,  ${}_{t} p_{x}$ and ${}_{t}^{} p_{x}^{n}$

Comment: This is the best answer as it uses plain Latex without any need for extra packages.

Answer (score 32):

The best solution I have seen so far was:

```
${}_{2}x_{1}$
```

[image: pic1]

For the more general case of left and right superscript and subscript, one writes:

```
${}^{1}_{2}x^{3}_{4}$
```

[image: pic2]

Comment: The question is about two subscript, one before and one after. It's not the same as having an upperscript and a subscript at the same place.

Comment: just added how you can have both in the same place and compared to some other solutions here I think this is rater simple in syntax.

Comment: As I said, you put a subscript and an upperscript and not two subscript

Comment: ah ok I see your point

Comment: Fixed that now. I did that because questions about left superscripts also get redirected to this post and marked as duplicates.

Comment: The indices are not aligned! :(

Answer (score 23):

The [`tensor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tensor) package will do exactly what you require, and more. For your particular case, you need only type

```
\tensor[_t]{p}{_x}
```

Regards

Answer (score 22):

You could use the [`leftidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/leftidx) package which is capable of producing left and right subscripts and superscripts.

In contrast to using simply consecutive subscripts or superscripts such as in `$_{t}p_{x}$` it takes care of adjusting indices to the argument using `\vphantom`. From its source:

```
\newcommand\leftidx[3]{%
  {\vphantom{#2}}#1#2#3%
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best approach IMHO.

Answer (score 17):

The `amsmath` package has a `\sideset` command which lets you put indices at all four corners of a symbol (even if this symbol itself has limits above/below):

```
\[  \sideset{_t}{_x}p  = \sideset{^*_*}{^*_*}\prod_*^*  \]
```

`\sideset` is intended to be used with large operator symbols such as `\sum` and `\prod`. *The amsmath documentation says: this command is not designed to be applied to anything other than sum-class symbols.* <sub>(Thanks to Stefan Kottwitz for this additional remark.)</sub>
For other symbols, have a look at the other answers here.

Comment: Good addition! Just a remark: `\sideset` is intended to be used with large operator symbols such as `\sum` and `\prod`. The amsmath documentation says: *this command is not designed to be applied to anything other than sum-class symbols.*

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, thanks ... I knew I should have looked it up before writing this. – So, don't use this with simple letter-symbols, use the other solutions given here.

Answer (score 11):

A simple method I apply - which does away with the need for extra packages - is the following:

```
~^o\!G_{Al}^i
```

Which produces the following:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think this solution is not ideal, because it will cause, at best, inconsistent spacing, or, at worst, a bad line break.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with the subscript and superscript, sooo I made a package to make my life easier and to other. 
It's a common problem with actuarial symbol, and it help align the sub and superscript.
Plus, I’ve add some shortcut to save time.

The project [page](https://vigou3.gitlab.io/actuarialsymbol/) and the [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol).

All you need is the actuarialsymbol package.

At the beginning of the code you have to write

```
\usepackage{actuarialsymbol}
```

For the sub/superscript

```
\actsymb['subscripLeft']['superscriptL']{<middle>}{'subscriptR'}{'superscriptR'}
```

Example of output:

[image]

Example of shortcut for actuarial symbol :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Is this meant as an answer for another question?

Comment: Congratulations! Nice package!

Comment: @Moriambar it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366883/ ;)

Comment: @clemens My package can fulfill many problems.

Comment: @Zarko thanks! If you have idea of upgrade we are open for it. We are working on a mathjax upgrade for ebook.

Answer (score 6):

I am dissatisfied with the existing options, including `\prescript` from `mathtools`, since they do not even make an attempt at fixing the spacing between the symbol and the left superscript. Therefore, based on [egreg’s excellent answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557655/low-level-command-for-controlling-left-superscript-spacing/557678#557678), I recently added the package [leftindex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/leftindex) to CTAN.
It provides the command

```
\leftindex^{<left superscript>}_{<left subscript>} {<symbol>}
```

This measures the negative indentation of the right subscript and indents the left superscript by the same value. This works well for most symbols, with a few exceptions, such as `A` and `L` (and `P` and `\Gamma` in some fonts other than Computer Modern).
Therefore, `\leftindex` takes a couple of optional arguments. The only one we shall need right now is

```
\leftindex[<slanting phantom>]^{<left superscript>}
    _{<left subscript>} {<symbol>}
```

If the command receives a `<slanting phantom>`, it will use this symbol instead of `<symbol>` to calculate the indentation of the left superscript.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{leftindex}

\begin{document}

Good results:
$
    \leftindex^a_b {f}, \leftindex^* {M}, \leftindex_q^p {H},
    \displaystyle
    \leftindex_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\int} f(x)\, dx
$

Bad results:
$
    \leftindex^* {A}, \leftindex^a_b {L}
$

With slanting correction:
$
    \leftindex[T]^* {A}, \leftindex[I]^a_b {L}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you grow tired of having to write slanting phantoms manually, you can have a look at my other package, [SemanTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex), which provides semantic, keyval-based mathematics where notation can be controlled centrally from the preamble. Its left index support is based on `leftindex`, but slanting phantoms can now be chosen once and for all from the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{semantex}

\NewVariableClass\MyVar[output=\MyVar]

% No slanting phantom needed:

\NewObject\MyVar\vf{f}

\NewObject\MyVar\vM{M}

\NewObject\MyVar\vH{H}

% Slanting phantom needed:

\NewObject\MyVar\vL{L}[slanting phantom=I]

\NewObject\MyVar\vGamma{\Gamma}[slanting phantom=]

% Slanting phantom and a \!\! to the
% right of the superscript needed:

\NewObject\MyVar\vA{A}[
    slanting phantom=I,
    post upper left=\!\!,
]

\begin{document}

$ \vf[upper left=a,lower left=b] $,
$ \vM[upper left=*] $,
$ \vH[upper left=p,lower left=q] $,

$ \vA[upper left=*] $,
$ \vL[upper left=a,lower left=b] $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution I adopt, whenever I'm working in environments where extra packages are unavailable, is to *manually* adjust the index position by adding spaces...

For example

```
{}_{a+b}^c Z
```

would result in

[image]

So, you could do

```
{}_{a+b}^{\quad c} Z
```

which gives

[image]

But you have to adjust them "case by case" till you find it *satisfactory*, for example

```
{}_{ab+\prod x_i}^{\quad\quad\ c} Z
```

[image]

Definitely, **punk-LaTex**, not ideal and not recommended, but sometimes useful when no better solution is available...

Answer (score -1):

I made one little improvement on Henrik L's answer:
I replace the `~` by `{}`

This removed the extra space given by ~

For my usage, this was important as I improved

```
$\Sigma _{~^{\wt M} \!  M^{(m)} }^{0,+}$
```

which appears as

[image]

to

```
$\Sigma _{{}^{\wt M} \!  M^{(m)} }^{0,+}$
```

which appears as

[image]
(ok, it's a complicated expression, but it's necessary, and this version makes it prettier!).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that MathJaX/MathML is not supported on TeX.SX, so you may want to change `$$ $$` into a screenshot :-)

Comment: The question is about placing subscripts on the left and right of the main character, so this doesn't really provide an answer.