# Annuity notation in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How do you write this in LaTeX:

[image]

Comment: Start here: [How to look up a math symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/2693)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with the actuarial symbol and the subscript/superscript, sooo I made a package to make my life easier and help other.

Plus, I’ve add some shortcut to save time.

The project [page](https://vigou3.gitlab.io/actuarialsymbol/) and the [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol).

All you need is the actuarialsymbol package.

At the beginning of the code you have to write

```
\usepackage{actuarialsymbol}
```

For the sub/superscript

```
\actsymb['subscripLeft']['superscriptL']{<middle>}{'subscriptR'}{'superscriptR'}
```

Example of output:

[image]

Example of shortcut for actuarial symbol :
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, and thanks for providing this announcement about the newly available package. It would he helpful is you also posted a compilable example -- borrowing code from some of the earlier answers would be entirely acceptable -- that shows the output produced by your package.

Answer (score 11):

In the thread [Actuarial & Annuity notation in LaTeX](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/67f557fe36f9c761/a10e0011362616db?lnk=gst&q=annuity%20%22arseneau%22&pli=1) from **text.comp.tex**, Donald Arseneau provided the following `\annu` command:

```
\def\annu#1{_{% 
  \vbox{\hrule height .2pt 
    \kern 1pt 
    \hbox{$\scriptstyle {#1}\kern 1pt$}% 
  }\kern-.05pt 
  \vrule width .2pt 
}}
```

with the additional comment:

> Tweak ".2pt" and "1pt" for appearance.

Comment: But you cant do it on this site?

Comment: @ annuitt Can't do what on this site? You now have two solutions to your problem *on this site*.  (Or do you mean why LaTeX markup isn't converted on this site?  If that's your question, it's because this site is mainly about the markup language (TeX/LaTeX) and having automatic conversion would defeat the purpose.) See this question [Can we turn off math-tex](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/181/2693) for reasons.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest to google for "actuarial" symbols and, of course, "LaTeX". You will find lots of examples, e.g. [Annuity or Angle Operation Symbol in LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89490/annuity-or-angle-operation-symbol-in-latex).

I solved that problem some years ago, if I only remembered the context. . .

---

**EDIT**

Some years later: There is a package for the actuarial angle, now in version 2:
https://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialangle

Comment: +1 for the `lifecon` package mentioned there.

Comment: @Keks: But how do you do it on sites like this?

Comment: How do you do what? On which sites? Sorry, I do not understand the question.

Comment: @annuitt Ah, now I understand, you'd like to write it as html here! Well, sorry, no idea!

Comment: There is now a better option with actuarialsymbol.

Answer (score 7):

You need the `actuarialange` package.

At the beginning of the code, you have to write

```
\usepackage{actuarialangle}
```

Then in math mode, to make the subscript “n” with the actuarial angle, you have to use one of these three commands:

```
\actuarialangle{n}
\angl{n}
\angln
```

Then for your task, the command is:

```
\[
a_{\actuarialangle{n}}
\]
```

Or if you want to write also the interest rate “i” the command is

```
\[
a_{\actuarialangle{n}i}
\]
```

Here's an example: in the `tabular`, the construction appears at natural size, but the commands should be used as subscripts like in the display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{actuarialangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\actuarialangle{n}| & $\actuarialangle{n}$ \\
\verb|\angl{n}| & $\angl{n}$ \\
\verb|\angln| & $\angln$
\end{tabular}

\[
a_{\actuarialangle{n}} \qquad a_{\actuarialangle{n}i}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I reformatted the post to conform to our usual standards.

Answer (score 5):

This symbol is in Unicode as U+20E7 (x⃧ ) and in `unicode-math` as `\annuity`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,actuarialangle} 
    %amssymb is needed for the urcorner symbol OR actuarialangle for the taller version

     %following two lines are only for this demo
    \usepackage[]{graphicx}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Actuarial_notation}\\
    Actuarial notation from \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation}\\
    \vspace{0.4 cm}

    %This is the full urcorner template to be reduced as one desires (see a typical example below)
    $m\mkern-8mu{\raisebox{0.8em}2} \vert
    \bar{\raisebox{0.5em}{\large{A}}}{\raisebox{0.8em}1}$
    $\mkern-12mu{\raisebox{-0.0em}{\textit{x:n}}\mkern-8mu\big\urcorner}$

    \vspace{0.4cm}

                    or for actuarialangle version
    \vspace{0.4cm}

    %This is the full Actuarialangle template to be reduced as one desires (see a typical example below)
    $m\mkern-8mu{\raisebox{0.8em}2} \vert{\bar{\raisebox{0.5em}{\large{A}}}{\raisebox{0.8em}1}\mkern-10mu{x\mkern-4mu:\mkern-4mu\actuarialangle{n}}}$

    \vspace{0.4cm}
                    or for a n other example
    \vspace{0.4cm}

    % bar A changed to ddot a, and several ''terms'' removed
    $\ddot{\raisebox{0.4em}{{a}}}$$\raisebox{-0.0em}{\textit{x:n}}\mkern-8mu\big\urcorner$\\
    $\ddot{a}_{x:\actuarialangle{n}} $ 

    \vspace{0.4cm}
    These are here as simple snippets to adjust rather than have to start from fresh
\end{document}
```