# Typesetting annuity and life-insurance symbols in ConTeXt

Tags: symbols, context, context-mkiv

How do I typeset annuity and life-insurance symbols, actuarial notation in ConTeXt.
I see there are packages available but not for ConTeXt.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of how they look like. I don't know those symbols.

Comment: From what I recall having seen some of the actuarial study material, there's nothing that can't be done using standard maths notation.  I think you'll need left sub- and superscripts, and some accents not normally used (`\urcorner` as an accent on a subscript)

Comment: for examples, see http://www.actuaries.org.uk/research-and-resources/documents/formulae-and-tables-actuarial-exams-1st-edition try starting at p33.

Comment: In the source code of [the Wikipedia page on actuarial notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation), the symbol is typeset as follows: `a_{\overline{n|}i}`.

Comment: although unicode recognizes the "actuarial bend" as a character, I doubt it can be easily produced as a single symbol in a font.  it certainly isn't acceptably represented by the upper right "quine corner" (`\urcorner`).

Comment: @Jubobs `a_{\overline{n|}i}` will have to do for the time being, will look for a prettier solution and post back, or finally just make the move to latex ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\urcorner` might not be ideal, but it's the best I can find, certainly better than the broken version provided in other comments.

Comment: `\urcorner` can never be acceptable for more than one letter at a time.  i don't have a tex system available to experiment, and won't for several weeks, but i will mark this question for a look when i return home, and if no other good answer has appeared by then, i will try to devise one in plain tex terms.  (i don't use context.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The symbol is present in stix fonts! Do you have any suggestion for the tex name for this symbol and its math class? I can add the corresponding definition to ConTeXt.

Comment: @barbarabeeton my hazy second hand recollection is that a single symbol is used under the corner, but if I'm wrong, of course it won't work, and of course it's always better to handle the general case.

Comment: Related: [Annuity notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25008/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Plain TeX, but I guess it can do for ConTeXt. Experts can improve it.

```
\def\actuarial#1{%
  \vbox{
    \offinterlineskip
    \tabskip=0pt
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \halign{##&\vrule##\cr
      \noalign{\hrule}%
      &height 1pt\cr
      $\scriptstyle#1$&\cr
    }%
  }%
}

$a_{\actuarial{n}}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I normally avoid using an explicit `\subscriptstyle`. It may be better to use `\mathpallet` to get automatic scaling of the argument.

Comment: @Aditya I don't know whether ConTeXt has `\mathpalette`. ;-). However I don't think this symbol is ever used in subscripts.

Comment: ConTeXt has almost all commands defined in plain TeX, so yes it has mathpalette, although the current practice is to use setmathstyle instead (basically assume that over etc will not be used so that the math style is predictable)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Barbara Beeton's comment, you just need to pick a font that includes the actuarial bend symbol. For example, using XITS fonts you get:

```
% Use a math font that has the actuarial bend symbol
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\setmathfont[XITS] 

\Umathchardef\actuarial "0 "0 "20E7

\starttext

$a_{n \actuarial}$

\stoptext
```

[image]

If someone can tell what is the right mathclass and tex name for this glyph, I can send in a request to add this to char-def.lua so that it works out of the box in ConTeXt.

Comment: The spacing seems wrong. The horizontal bar should not touch the preceding letters.

Comment: @Marco: Tell that to the glyph designer :) (But it could also be something due to incorrect scaling in subscripts)

Comment: The scaling of the subscripts is correct. This looks OK if a wider glyph is used.

Comment: so the basic glyph really should be narrower, and horizontally extendable.  i'll forward that comment for consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you going, you may want to tweak the `raisebox` dimension, and the negative spaces, and maybe the size of the `\urcorner`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\bend}[1]{\smash{#1\!\!\!{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\big\urcorner}}}}
\begin{document}
This is horrible:

$a_{\overline{n|}i}$

This isn't great, but is much better:

$a_{\bend{n} i}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

No doubt someone can propose a cleaner way of doing the adjustments, I can update for comments.

Also it will need testing in ConTeXt - I don't use it, though from what I've read it *should* work.