# In-line long division symbol (French style)

Tags: symbols

I am looking for long division symbol for inline use. For US style there are [several choices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/better-way-to-display-long-division).

For displayed long division, French style, there is [`xlop` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xlop).

I am looking for the inline version, French style, which, for `$x \div y$`,  would look something like an `$x\ L y$` with `$y$` inside `$L$`.

Comment: Almost the opposite of [How to Produce a Half-Box Symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149087/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use an array without intercolumn space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\frenchdiv}[2]{%
  #1\:\begin{array}[t]{@{\vline}l@{}}\,#2\,\\\hline\end{array}%
}

\begin{document}
$\frenchdiv{84}{7}=12$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `\vline`? Is it similar to `|`? From your code I understand it is being used as a column separator, right?

Comment: @azetina Using `\vline` avoids undesirable spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun. Of course the link @Werner gave you is a good start. Notice that what I did was just to play around with someone else's [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131138/10898). See MWE below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\frenchdiv[2]{%
$\strut#1$\kern.25em\smash{\raise-.35ex\hbox{\rule{0.4pt}{2ex}}}$\mkern-0.72mu
        \underline{\,#2}$}

\begin{document}

\frenchdiv{56}{3678}\quad\frenchdiv{3}{37678}

\end{document}
```

Taking now the following [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149092/10898) an playing around with the node anchors, we have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\nfrenchdiv[2]{#1\,%
  \tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{\node(n)[inner sep=1pt]{$#2$};
    \draw[line cap=round](n.north west)--(n.south west)--(n.south east);
  }
}

\begin{document}

$\nfrenchdiv{56}{3678}$

\end{document}
```

Note that this command may not be robust. So, wait for other possible responses and choose the best that suites your needs.