# Symbol division latex

Tags: diagrams

I am studying the phasor method for solving electrical circuits. Have tried using tables and researched a lot on the internet but have not found a simple command to represent the numbers a and b in the diagram below:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Sigur I think this is not a duplicate of the linked question; there, the goal is to effectively calculate the division; here, the OP is interested just in the division-like symbol, but without any calculations.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I was guided by the title therein *How to make the traditional division?*

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Voted to reopen but my Guess: Possible Duplicate of [In-line long division symbol (French style)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149975/15717)

Answer (score 3):

If it is simply a diagram, you can use a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Phasor[2]{%
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}  %% change 2pt suitably
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
  #1 & #2 \\\cline{2-2}
  \end{tabular}
  }
\begin{document}
  This is \Phasor{a}{b} well a phasor.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Certainly one can use `tikz` but, for a change, I would not present one. But if you are interested, that is a different case ;)

Answer (score 1):

In phasors, the electrical quantities are represented by a magnitude and an angle. The symbol for the angle is not the same as the inline  traditional division symbol, but `\angle` is used in math mode for this.

For example for an R-L circuit with V and I can be expressed as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
V_{sm} &= V_m \angle \phi,\quad  \textup{and}\\
   I_m &= I_m \angle \theta
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complex formulae one should go with the [Steinmetz](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/steinmetz/steinmetz.pdf) package as pointed out in the comment of egreg. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Inductor, $L$: $\mathbf{Z}=j\omega L=\omega L\phase{90^{\circ}}$,
\item Capacitor, $C$: $\displaystyle\mathbf{Z}=\frac{1}{j\omega C}=-j\frac{1}{\omega C}=\frac{1}{\omega C}\phase{-90^{\circ}}$.
\item  $\mathbf{Z}= \phase{\alpha+\beta}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: The `steinmetz` package has been thought for this application.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, thanks