# Actuarial notation

Tags: symbols

The symbol that sits over this subscript "n" is used frequently in "actuarial notation".  How should it be coded in LaTeX?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Actuarial_notation.svg

Comment: see [Annuity notation in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25008/579)

Comment: There are lot of attempts. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149087/how-to-produce-a-half-box-symbol/149090#149090 and those with the keyword `actuarial` or `annuity`.