# Can't find a command for actuarial angle

Tags: amsmath, amssymb

I'm trying to properly render the following formula:

[image]

This is what I've got so far:

```
aufgel"ost nach $B^A$ ergibt sich

\begin{equation}
    \boxed{B^A = \mathit{VS} \cdot \frac{_{\textbar n}A_x + \mathrm{"a}_{x:n} \cdot \gamma}{(1 - \beta) \cdot \mathrm{"a}_{x:t} - t \cdot \alpha^Z}}
\end{equation}

bzw. f"ur $t = n$
```

Rendered result:

[image: result]

However, I can't find the symbol for the actuarial angle for the letters `n` and `t` in the numerator and denominator in the AMS symbols list.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140172/82917 might be something for you.

Comment: @campa great, thank you so much! Your comment pointed me to the correct name of the symbol - the actuarial angle! Knowing this, I immediately found a package that provides the command: [`actuarialangle`](https://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialangle). If you will write a short answer, I will glady upvote and accept it.

Comment: I have made a few minor changes that may help without resorting to another package
\begin{equation}
    \boxed{B^A = \mathit{VS} \cdot \frac{_{\mid n}A_x + \ddot a_{x:n\mkern-6mu\urcorner} \cdot \gamma}{(1 - \beta) \cdot \ddot a_{x:t\mkern-6mu\urcorner}   - t \cdot \alpha^Z}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this may be closed as a dup of [Typesetting annuity and life-insurance symbols in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140065/typesetting-annuity-and-life-insurance-symbols-in-context), a note to future readers - instead of using a self-made construct suggested in its accepted answer, consider using the `actuarialangle` for the symbol in LaTeX. The package is part of TeXLive, so you don't need to install anything else. Here's what the above formula looks like in the end:

```
\usepackage[thickspace,nobracket]{actuarialangle}

...

\begin{equation}
    \boxed{B^A = \mathit{VS} \cdot \frac{_{\textbar n}A_x + \mathrm{"a}_{x:\actuarialangle{n}} \cdot \gamma}{(1 - \beta) \cdot \mathrm{"a}_{x:\actuarialangle{t}} - t \cdot \alpha^Z}}
\end{equation}
```

Rendered output:

[image]

[Source](https://vigou3.gitlab.io/actuarialsymbol/).

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate: the `actuarialangle` package is not available for ConTeXt, whereas it's exactly meant for such applications in LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg thanks, this was the main point of writing the answer. However, I think my question may be a duplicate of [Annuity notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25008/annuity-notation-in-latex) - maybe it makes sense to link that instead.

Comment: Yes, that's more adherent to a LaTeX user's needs; also another package is mentioned.

Comment: I have tried to make a simplistic TeX boilerplate for the Annuity bit in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455754/170109 so for your first usage case it would be like the second example on that page and for your second usage here it could be $\ddot{\raisebox{0.3em}{\large{a}}}$$\raisebox{-0.2em}{\textit{x:t}}\mkern-7mu\big\urcorner$

Comment: @KJO I get an error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \left \urcorner`. Looks like `\urcorner` is an unknown command.

Comment: \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} works for me perhaps you don't have the symbol part ? guess that contradicts my statement of not needing other packages !duh

Comment: Oops, my bad! Have commented `\usepackage{amssymb}` out because unused. The code compiles just fine! However, it does look a bit different from the `actuarialangle`, the lines are shorter: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmUWJ.png).

Comment: Agreed it is a kludge but nearest symbol in the common packages I could find without the previous user attempts to build variations and without loading a dedicated package that's sometimes not on web based editors which I used to test if results looked fairly similar

Comment: I have updated my template answer to include comments on package requirements (thanks) and given both urcorner and acturialangle as discussed here, oddly the default lowercase a is different with each sample !