# How do I format the following equation in LaTex?

Tags: math-mode

What packages and commands do I need to format the following equation into a LaTeX document (ignore the background, I just need the equation)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way, I think)
[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
 \usepackage{actuarialangle}


 \begin{document}

 $s_{\actuarialangle{n}i}=\frac{(1+i)^{n}-1}{i}$

 \end{document}
```

Comment: The screenshot you posted doesn't correspond fully to the code above. For one, the code uses `s`, but the screenshot shows `S`. In addition, the math mode in use the screenshot looks to be `\displaystyle`, whereas the code employs `\textstyle`. Please fix.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
s_{\smash{\overline{n}}\vrule\,i}=\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A modification of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140172/4427

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\annuity}{mo}{%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{
      \offinterlineskip
      \mathsurround=0pt
      \ialign{##&\vrule##\cr
        \noalign{\hrule}%
        &height 1pt\cr
        $\scriptstyle#1\hskip\scriptspace$&\cr
      }%
    }%
    \IfValueT{#2}{$\scriptstyle\,#2$}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
s_{\annuity{n}[i]}=\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}
\]
\[
s_{\annuity{n}}\quad s_{\annuity{p}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]