# Joint-Life First-Survivor Insurance Symbol

Tags: symbols

I get an error when trying to produce the following symbol: `Command \scriptsize invalid in math mode`. I'm not sure how to get around it in this case after doing some searching...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A^{\hspace{0.35cm}1}_{\scriptsize\overbrace{40:50}:\overline{10}|}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be even better if I could get the subscript written without any extra spaces (like 40:50).

`lifecon` does not have this symbol, to my knowledge.

If I do not customize the size on the subscript, I get the following:

[image]

whose numbers 40:50 are too big.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A^{\hspace{0.35cm}1}_{\overbrace{40{:}50}:\overline{10}|}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the command is `\scriptstyle`  not `\scriptsize` but script size is automatic in a subscript so you can just delete the command. use `{:}` to get tight spacing

Comment: For the annuity symbol, see the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25008/3954

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - See my edit

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - The annuity symbol is not of concern; it is trying to size the 40:50 appropriately.

Comment: @Clarinetist I *know* what your question is. Sorry for trying to suggest you how to improve your code. I promise I won't do it again.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Apologies if I came off the wrong way. I didn't find anything particularly helpful on that website, to be honest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

\def\annu#1{{% 
  \vbox{\hrule height .2pt 
    \kern 1pt 
    \hbox{$\scriptstyle {#1}\kern 1pt$}% 
  }\kern-.05pt 
  \vrule width .2pt 
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A^{\mathclap{\phantom{\,\scriptstyle 40:50\,}1}}_{\overbrace{\scriptstyle 40:50}:\annu{10}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

For the annuity I used the definition in the answer to [Annuity notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25008/3954).

Comment: I've propose a cleaner solution with the package actuarialsymbol.

Answer (score 3):

This?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\[
A{\scriptstyle\overbrace{\scriptstyle 40{:}50}^1:\overline{10}|}
\]
\end{document}
```

Or replaceing both `\scriptsyle` by `\scriptscriptstyle` :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the actuarial symbol and the subscript/superscript, sooo I made a package to make my life easier and help other.

Plus, I’ve add some shortcut to save time.

The project [page](https://vigou3.gitlab.io/actuarialsymbol/) and the [CTAN](http://ttp://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol).

All you need is the actuarialsymbol package.

At the beginning of the code you have to write

```
\usepackage{actuarialsymbol}
```

For the sub/superscript

```
\actsymb['subscripLeft']['superscriptL']{<middle>}{'subscriptR'}{'superscriptR'}
```

Example of output:

[image]

[image]

Example of shortcut for actuarial symbol :
[image]