# How to write actuarial symbols with Katex

Tags: formatting

I use a web application that uses the Katex language. However, I would like to create actuarial symbols such as for example this below...

Would anyone know how I could simply make this symbol?

[image: Actuarial symbol]

Comment: You may get some ideas in [Annuity notation in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25008/82917). But if this is about how to get this to work in KaTeX, I fear it is off-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because KaTeX is not TeX, but is based on JavaScript and can't use TeX features that are not implemented in it.