# How should I align capital letter subscripts?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I observe that when a word starts with capital letter or non-capital letter as a subscript, then the capital letter looks like it shifted right, as an eye illusion. But when I look closely `a` and `A` actually started at exact location.

example:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\phantom{} \\
    \(C_{a}^{\mathit{pull}}\) \\
    \(C_{A}^{\mathit{pull}}\) \\
    \(C_{d}^{\mathit{pull}}\) \\
    \(C_{D}^{\mathit{pull}}\) \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `A` looks like it starts kind of 1 space inside. If I use a capitalize word should I shift it left using: `$C_{!\A}$` or is there more proper way to do it?

Comment: It seems like this is more unique to `A` than to capital letters in general, since `A` is the only one with stuff in its bottom left corner but not its top left corner.  But I think the question still remains for `A`.

Comment: @Teepeemm I observe same for `D` as well

Comment: The leftmost part of A and D are aligned with the p of pull. Probably the same with E, F etc.

Comment: @PeterWilson that's right but `A` and `D` looks like they shifted 1 space to right compared to `a` or `d`

Comment: The nature of the glyph. You can see that the glyph starts at the same position: `$C_{D}^{\mathit{pull}}$\llap{$C_{d}^{\mathit{pull}}$}`. `D` contains the serif at the bottom.

Comment: Adjustment would improve the appearance, certainly, but it can't be done automatically, since TeX is aware only of the width of a glyph.  Consider "W" and "Y", which have their greatest width at the top, along with an indentation at the baseline.

Comment: As far as LaTeX typesetting is concerned a character is a rectangular box with some graphic inside it. It only deals with the boxes, not their content. See @barbarabeeton's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more I look at the picture, the less I feel a need for “fixing”. Anyway, here's the experiment: I define a `\fixA` command that emits a negative kern. In the four columns, the kerns are zero, `-1mu`, `-2mu` and `-3mu` respectively, the last being the same as `\!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fixA}[1][1]{\mkern-#1mu}

\begin{document}

\spaceskip=1em

\(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\(C_{A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{\fixA A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{\fixA[2] A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{\fixA[3] A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `IEEEtran`, I recommend using `newtx` in order to get Times font also in math (the standard Computer Modern is really unsuited to go with Times). Now you can compare and see that using something like `\fixA` is better than hardwiring `\!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtx}

\newcommand{\fixA}[1][1]{\mkern-#1mu}

\begin{document}

\spaceskip=1em

\(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{a}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\(C_{A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{\fixA A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{\fixA[2] A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{\fixA[3] A}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{d}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\) \(C_{D}^{\mathrm{pull}}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead `\usepackage{newtx}` can I only use `\usepackage{newtxmath}`? I observe that section titles also effected when I use `newtxtext` and fonts in `listings`; I believe journals wouldn't what their template section fons to be affected

Comment: Or can we apply `\usepackage{newtx}` only for the math-mode? like the text in between `$...$`? and not not effect the text in between `\section{ ... }`

Comment: @alper You might by doing `\usepackage{newtxmath}`, but the class uses `ptm` for text, which points to a very old font, whereas `newtx` is richer.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** *I am the author of the package and of the linked solution.*

You can take a look at my LaTeX package to handle super and under script based on the actuarial symbol. It can handle by default most super, under script with package function also.

[See here my response here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366883/132281).

Comment: I was looking for much simple solution where `\(C_{\!D}}\)` would be enough?

Comment: Yes, but I think interfacing with a command is much simpler IMO.