# LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared. when I try to include newtx

Tags: amsthm, newtx

I am using following complete-template at overleaf [Elsevier's CAS LaTeX Double-Column Template - Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-double-column-template/hhzpymgjmxfk). Whey I try to add `newtx` package using  `\usepackage{newtx}`, I get a compilation error.

bare tex:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{Leveraging social media news}
\shortauthors{CV Radhakrishnan et~al.}
\title [mode = title]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title}
\tnotemark[1,2]
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\begin{abstract}
    This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.
    \noindent\texttt{\textbackslash begin{abstract}} \dots
    \texttt{\textbackslash end{abstract}} and
    \verb+\begin{keyword}+ \verb+...+ \verb+\end{keyword}+
    which
    contain the abstract and keywords respectively.

    \noindent Each keyword shall be separated by a \verb+\sep+ command.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
The Elsevier cas-dc class is based on the
\end{document}
```

---

Based on following answer ([How can I prevent newtx to change fonts format in `\section{}` and `\subsection{}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659960/how-can-i-prevent-newtx-to-change-fonts-format-in-section-and-subsection/659968#659968)); I have tried to include `newtx` to gain space. I am not sure do I require to add it since I am not using `IEEEtran`.

When I try to add `\usepackage{newtx}` I am getting following error:

```tex
amsthm NOT loaded

! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.614 ...lareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{ntxsyc}{m}{n}

?
```

Is it possible to fix this error?

Comment: you are already loading stix which is a times-like font, do you need the tx times clone for math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are already loading stix which is a times-like font, do you need the tx times clone for math?

You could suppress stix as shown, or more in the spirit of the class would be to keep stix and use `newtxtext` so only change text fonts.

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@stix.sty\endcsname{}
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtx}
```

Normally when using a publisher class it is best not to change fonts *at all* the whole point  of the class is to force the publisher house style

Comment: Can I keep `\usepackage{newtxtext}` ? // I believe it also changes the fonts but did not created any compilation error.

Comment: @alper you can for me, it may annoy elsevier if you submit to their journal but that's not a technical issue