# annihilator symbol

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left and right subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript)

I want to use annihilators in maths. I can write `$I^\perp$` but I do not know how I can write `perp` in left hand side not the right hand side. Would you please help me in this regard.

Sorry for the poor English in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicates are : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30554/superscripts-before-a-letter-in-math and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript You can also search for `\sideset` and `\prescript` commands on this site.

Comment: Would `$^{\perp}I$` do it?