# The \prescript command from the mathtools package gives incorrect alignment

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, mathtools

The spacing I'm getting with the `\prescript` command from the `mathtools` package seems wrong. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\prescript{14}{2}{\mathbf{C}}^{5+}_{2}$
\end{document}
```

which produces this (red line added to make difference clearer):

[image]

I suspect it's just a problem with the command itself - if so, is there a known fix? If not, what should I be doing differently? (Of course, regardless of whose fault it is, one solution is just to use a different package for this purpose.)

Comment: Related: [Superscripts before a letter in math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30554/5764)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A concise solution in this instance is presented via the [`tensor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tensor):

[image]

```
$\tensor*[^{14}_2]{\mathbf{C}}{^{5+}_2}$
```

---

Not sure about the extent of your usage, but the following also corrects this in your specific case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,leftidx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{mathtools,leftidx}
\begin{document}
$\prescript{14\phantom{+}}{2}{\mathbf{C}}^{5+}_{2}$ \quad
$\leftidx{^{14\vphantom{+}}_2}{\mathbf{C}}{^{5+}_2}$ \quad
$\vphantom{\mathbf{C}}^{14\vphantom{+}}_{\phantom{14}\mathllap{2}}\mathbf{C}^{5+}_2$
\end{document}
```

The [`leftidx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/leftidx) provides `\leftidx{<left>}{<base>}{<right>}` prints `<base>` with a left index `<left>` and right index `<right>`. However, it also suffers from the same problem by default. The alternative is to set `<base>` twice, first only as a `\vphantom`. The use of `\vphantom{+}` is to also improve the adjustment vertically. Horizontal alignment for the left index is achieved via `\phantom{14}\mathllap{2}`.

Comment: BTW: which tool gives us such a thin (red) ruler?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: `\par\vspace*{-0.70\baselineskip}{\color{red}\hrulefill}`

Comment: Thank you! Only TeX! I thought that it is a ruler from some graphic tool.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth: for ions like this the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package (or rather it's sub-package `chemformula` that in a yet to come v4.0 will be usable stand-alone but until then itself would load `chemmacros`) aligns all subscripts (and superscripts). It also takes care of the IUPAC recommendation for staggered sub- and superscripts (see [IUPAC Green Book](http://www.iupac.org/nc/home/projects/project-db/project-details.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Bproject_nr%5D=110-2-81)) which could be prevented using an option, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{^{14}2\textbf{C}2^{5+}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{charge-hshift=0pt}
\begin{document}

\ch{^{14}2\textbf{C}2^{5+}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestion! Even though I will not be writing any chemistry expressions myself (I probably should have explained that I was only using this because it's an example presented in the `mathtools` documentation), it's useful to know that the `chemmacros` / `chemformula` package can be used as an alternative by setting the option you mentioned. Hopefully chemists are using these superior packages already and don't have to worry about issues with `\prescript` :)

Comment: @ZevChonoles Well, I don't know about “superior” but you're right: they're specifically taylored for chemists…

Comment: I certainly knew that; I think whatever I was trying to say with my last sentence made much more sense in my head at the time. At any rate, thanks again :)