# Sub and superscript on the left

Tags: spacing, subscripts, superscripts

I want to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   Hom_{K\cap {}_a^bK}  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But there seems that the `_a^b` is on the `\cap` and not attached to the `K`.

How might I do this right?

Comment: Related: [The `\prescript` command from the `mathtools` package gives incorrect alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109694/5764); [Superscripts before a letter in math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30554/5764)

Comment: Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript

Comment: @nrpeterson: I did take a look at that, but I can't get that to work. Can you show me in an answer how I might do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 9):

None of the mentioned packages would give a good result in this case, because TeX suppresses space around binary operations in subscripts.

A good solution for this particular case seems to be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,leftidx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\begin{document}
\[
   \Hom_{K\cap \,\leftidx{_a^b}{\!K}{}}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `\,` pushes right the right operand a bit, so to separate it from the intersection symbol. The `K` would however be too detached from the prescripts, so I add a small correction.

[image]