# More basic versions of \prescript

Tags: packages, mathjax

Sometimes I want to put a subscript or superscript to the left of an argument. In LaTeX documents, I have used the `\prescript` command from the `mathtools` package, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109694/the-prescript-command-from-the-mathtools-package-gives-incorrect-alignment). But Mathjax does not recognize this command. Is there an alternative using more basic commands that might be supported by Mathjax?

Comment: Hello! While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try insteead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: yeh, i hesitated to post the question here but the I searched for *mathjax* in this forum and got lots of results, thus i decided to post it here

Comment: Well, one point is that people who understand MathJaX in general don't visit this site. I guess the best place for help is the Google group.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that - rarely there is someone on Stackexchange recommending Google Group ;-)

Comment: In a pinch, I think `${}_{2}C$` would probably work, more or less, to put a prescript 2 before a C.

Comment: @Charles Staats That works great thanks! You like to write it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a pinch, a prescript can be created after a fashion by putting a subscript on a preceeding empty character; for instance, `${}_{ij} C$` produces a letter C with a prescript ij.

Answer (score 4):

Pure MathJax issues are off topic, so I'll give a mostly LaTeX answer but note that the commands are supported by MathJax.

If you go `{}_2X` it works in simple cases but it is a subscript of the empty `{}` so if you replace `X` by anything larger the prescript will be misplaced as it does not take account of the base.

the `amsmath` `\sideset` command is designed for this use but only with large operators like sum `\sideset{_2}{}\sum`

MathML has a prescripts mechanism using `<mmultiscripts>` and `<mprescripts>` so in MathJaX you also have the possibility of directly accessing those rather than relying on conversion from some "standard" LaTeX package markup. You can generate any MatHML element from the TeX MathJax syntax using `\mmlToken`.