# Prevent "jumping" \prescript stars

Tags: vertical-alignment, superscripts, left-superscripts

Look at the alignment of the following two formulas:

`X^* \cong \prescript{*}{}{X}`

[image]

The right stare, produced with `\prescript`, is higher than the left one.
One solution from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109694/the-prescript-command-from-the-mathtools-package-gives-incorrect-alignment) suggests a `\vphantom` inside the `\prescript`, which doesn't change anything here since the two stars are the same size.

Here is a related problem:

`\prescript{*}{}{\left(X^*\right)} \cong X \cong \left(\prescript{*}{}{X}\right)^*`

[image]

Maybe the different heights here are caused by the different sizes of `X` and `(`.

*In both cases, how do I align the stars to be on the same height?*

Comment: why not just use `^*(X^*) \cong X \cong (^*X)^* `, as this solves the height-problem? (possibly remove some spacing). Of course prescript should work the same way, so your question is of course relevant to improve consistency among packages. I guess `\prescript`is from `mathtools`, so it should probably be fixed there.

Comment: @runartrollet, good point, I didn't think of it! Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: You are misusing `\left` and `\right`, that should not appear in this context.

Comment: @egreg, I was previously under the impression that the brackets were larger if I put something with a superscript inside. Good to learn I was wrong.

Comment: You may get larger delimiters with `$\left(X^*\right)$`, but you don't need them; `$(X^*)$` is as clear (and more typographically sound).

Comment: @runartrollet, the horizontal spacing is not very good, as you say. But in my first example, even the vertical spacing comes out incorrectly.

Comment: @egreg, if it would give me larger delimiters, why would the smaller ones be considered sound (since apparently the content is too big for them)?

Comment: There's no need to cover the complete height; the most instructive example is the comparison between `\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)` and `\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\biggr)` in a displayed formula: the latter is good, the former has too big delimiters. Also consider the depth: a bigger delimiter also has bigger depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  the `fouridx` package instead:

*Edit:*

I also included the suggestion by the O.P. to smash the parentheses in order to have lower `*`s

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{fouridx}

\begin{document}

\[ \fourIdx{*}{}{*}{}{\!(X})\quad (\fourIdx{*}{}{*}{}{\!X)} \]

\[ \fourIdx{*}{}{*}{}{\!\smash{(}X})\quad (\fourIdx{*}{}{*}{}{\!X\smash{)}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For completeness, in order to avoid the * peeking so high out of the brackets, I went for `\fourIdx{*}{}{*}{}{\smash{(}X})`, which reduces the vertical size of `(` to zero.

Comment: @Turion: That's a fine idea! I'll add it to my answer, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Although this should be fixed for consistensy in `mathtools`, a fix could be to do something like this, as my original comment mentioned:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
% Original code, \prescript at wrong height
    \prescript{*}{}{\left(X^*\right)} \cong X \cong \left(\prescript{*}{}{X}\right)^*\\
% Just with ^* (no \prescript), also no \left \right, since it's just a single line with no symbols larger than current line
    ^*(X^*) \cong X \cong (^*X)^* \\
% And some cahnge in spacing
    ^*(X^*) \cong X \cong (^*\mkern-4mu X)^* \\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Just a suggestion: the kerning should depend on the fontsize, so you might use something like `^*\mkern-3mu` (adapt the value to what fits best, of course. I used this as it corresponds to `\!`).

Comment: @Bernard You are of course right. I added the change. Thank you.