# Scalable paired delimiter with subscript as both pre- and postscript

Tags: subscripts, delimiters, mathtools

I'm trying to define a command that, given input on the form `\mydef{pre}{main}{post}`, gives output akin to:

[image: 1]

(Where the "foo" and "bar" are just for reference, and the fraction inside is to provide a tall input.) That is, I want a paired delimiter with arguments for pre- and postscripts as subscripts. I want an unscaled default version, and preferably a starred version which scales automatically depending on `main`, but where the prescript is aligned with the postscript. The above is generated by the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\mydef}[3]{_{#1}}{[}{]}{_{#3}}{#2}

\begin{document}

\[
    foo \mydef*{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} bar
\]

\end{document}
```

I figured that the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` command provided by [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en) was a good start, but I can't seem to get the prescript to align properly.

The `\prescript` command provided by the same package might be useful, but if you are going to recommend it, remember that it renders subscripts as if there were a superscript as well, which I don't want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    {}_{pre} main \quad \prescript{}{pre}{main} \quad {}_{pre}^{} main
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: 3]

So I would want a way around that.

Comment: How you want the prescript to align is not clear. Could you give more details?

Comment: @Bernard I want the prescript to align vertically with the postscript. That is, they should be the same "height", but otherwise it should appear exactly as above.

Comment: To be precise: The placement of the postscript above is good. It is the placement of the prescript that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109695 you can use the `tensor` package, e.g., `\newcommand{\mydef}[3]{\tensor*[_{#1}]{#2}{_{#3}}}`.

Comment: @Marijn That seems to do the job reasonably well. I'm still not convinced about the vertical placement, but that's beyond this particular question, I think.

Answer (score 2):

here's a rather sledgehammer-ish approach.

two methods are shown.  the first -- the "obvious" approach -- doesn't work.  i
haven't figured out why.

the important point is the requirement to specify `\displaystyle` when constructing the box.  i failed to apply that at first, and the pre-script was set too high.  after i realized what the problem was, i tried fixing it in both places.  unfortunately, the attempt to apply a phantom fails.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\mydefa}{[}{]}

\newcommand{\mydef}[3]{%
  \vphantom{\displaystyle\mydefa*{#2}}_{#1}\mydefa*{#2}_{#3}}

\newcommand{\mydefb}[3]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle\mydefa*{#2}$}%
  \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\ht0} _{#1}\mydefa*{#2}_{#3}}

\begin{document}

trying to use a \verb+\vphantom+:
\[
    foo \mydef{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} bar
\]

using the dimensions of the box created from the core element:
\[
    foo \mydefb{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} bar
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

With `\mydef` we simply grab whatever happens to be up to the first brace, then pass control to `\mydefA` that grabs the real arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\mydef}{}% initialize
\def\mydef#1#{\mydefA{#1}}
\newcommand{\mydefA}[4]{%
  \mathopen{}\mathclose{\vphantom{\mydefB#1{#3}}}_{#2}\kern-\scriptspace
  \mydefB#1{#3}_{#4}%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\mydefB}{[}{]}

\begin{document}

\[
x \mydef*{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} y \mydef[\Big]{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} z
\]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, and perhaps easier to understand,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mydef}{sO{}mmm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\mathopen{}\mathclose{\vphantom{\mydefB*{#4}}}_{#3}\kern-\scriptspace\mydefB*{#4}_{#5}}%
   {\mathopen{}\mathclose{\vphantom{\mydefB[#2]{#4}}}_{#3}\kern-\scriptspace\mydefB[#2]{#4}_{#5}}%
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\mydefB}{[}{]}

\begin{document}

\[
x \mydef*{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} y \mydef[\Big]{pre}{\frac{main}{main}}{post} z
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]