# pre-subscript alignment with tensor package

Tags: subscripts, mathtools, tensor

I am trying to typeset the hypergeometric function 2F3 with subscript 2 and 3. Specifically, I want the correct alignment of the pre-subscript 2, like in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
  \[
    3{}_2F_3(\cdot)
  \]
  \[
    3\prescript{}{2}{F}_3(\cdot)
  \]
  \[
    3\tensor*[_2]{F}{_3}(\cdot)
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick `{}_2F_3` gives the correct spacing, but I would like to use a better method.

Using `\prescript` from `mathtools` gives the wrong vertical alignment, as already noticed in [The \prescript command from the mathtools package gives incorrect alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109694/)

The `\tensor` and `\tensor*` commands from `tensor` should provide the correct alignment. Unfortunately, using them the 2 prescript is slightly moved to the left, too close to the number 3 and too distant from F. Is this a bug?

Is there a better way to typeset 2F3 correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I'd use `{}_2F_3` personally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No package needed (here I load `amsmath` because any document with mathematics should).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hypgeo}[2]{%
  {\vphantom{F}}_{#1}\kern-\scriptspace F_{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

$\hypgeo{2}{3}$

$3\,\hypgeo{2}{3}$

\end{document}
```

Note the removal of `\scriptspace` to move the prescript next to the F. A thin space should be inserted between a factor and the hypergeometric function symbol.

This insertion can be made automatic by making the symbol into an operator (and here `amsmath` has a role):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hypgeo}[2]{%
  \operatorname{%
    {\vphantom{\mathnormal{F}}}_{#1}%
    \kern-\scriptspace
    \mathnormal{F}_{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\hypgeo{2}{3}$

$3\hypgeo{2}{3}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to create a command called `\hypergeo` for typing, well, hypergeometric functions. My solution utilizes the [`actuarialsymbol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/actuarialsymbol) package, which was released last year.

For a description of the “alignment of sub/superscripts problem” arose in actuarial notations, please take a look at Page 3 of the [`actuarialsymbol` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/actuarialsymbol/actuarialsymbol.pdf). Although this package deals with actuarial notations, but I think it is useful for typing hypergeometric functions as well.

The syntax of `\hypergeo` is

```
\hypergeo[<left-subscript>][<left-superscript>]{<right-subscript>}[<right-superscript>]
```

The `<right-subscript>` argument is *mandatory* (can be empty `{}`) while the other three are *optional*. If you declare, instead, the following

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hypergeo}{\@actinssc F}
```

Then a starred version `\hypergeo*` is created in addition to `\hypergeo`, in which the `F` will be automatically replaced by `\bar{F}`. This may be useful if you want something like `{}_2\bar{F}_3`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{actuarialsymbol}
\newcommand*\hypergeo{}% make sure this has not been defined yet
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hypergeo}{\@actothersc F}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  $
    3{}_2F_3(\cdot)
  $\par
%  \[
%    3\prescript{}{2}{F}_3(\cdot)
%  \]
%  \[
%    3\tensor*[_2]{F}{_3}(\cdot)
%  \]
  $
    3\hypergeo[2]{3}(\cdot) \quad 3\hypergeo[2]{3}[(n)](\cdot)
  $
\end{document}
```

[image: hypergeometric function]

In the second formula of the second line, notice how the left-subscript `2` and right-subscript `3` are both lowered when a superscript `(n)` is present (although I don’t think this is a common notation).