# Power indices on the left side

Tags: math-mode, spacing, positioning

I'm using `{^2K}` to write the indices on the left side, but when I do so I get an unwanted space between `2` en `K`. Is there another way to write the "power" indices on the left side?

```
\section*{text}
\fbox{\parbox{38em}{
\textbf{text} 
\textit{text}
\begin{eqnarray}
f^{(M)}(z)\underbrace{(K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_M)}_\text{operandi}= \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \sum\limits_{j_1=1}^m \sum\limits_{j_2=1}^m \ldots \sum\limits_{j_M=1}^m {^if_{j_1 j_2\ldots j_M}}{^{j_1}K_1}{^{j_2}K_2}\ldots{^{j_M}K_Me_i},
\end{eqnarray}
waarbij $z$ het argument is en
\begin{eqnarray}
K_t &=& [{^1K_t, ^2K_t,\ldots, ^mK_t}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^m, \qquad t = 1,2,\ldots,M, \nonumber \\
{^if_{j_1 j_2\ldots j_M}} &=& \frac{\partial^M{^if(z)}}{\partial^{j1}z\partial^{j2}z\ldots\partial^{jM}z},
\end{eqnarray}
}
```

The result that I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9maMO.jpg)

I'd like to make the sapce there smaller, or to write {^2K_t} in another away.

PS how can I remove the unwanted space [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gQYg.jpg)

Comment: On the left side of what? You need to be way more specific in your question.

Comment: on the left side of K
as if you'd write K^2 but the 2 has to be on the elft side

Comment: Can you add a little code example (MWE) to clarify what you want? If you are looking for something like chemical formulas, have a look at [chemmacros](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) or [mhchem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem)

Comment: @Fizunik: You can eliminate the space using `\!`. So in this case, you could say `$^2\!K$`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Jake, yes it worked, tyvm

Comment: Th space is there because of the *italic* of variables in the math mode. `$^2$K` or `$^2\mathrm{K}$` don't have the space.

Comment: and this is the code

\begin{eqnarray}
K_t &=& [{^1\!K_t, ^2\!K_t,\ldots, ^m\!K_t}]^T \in \mathbb{R}^m, \qquad t = 1,2,\ldots,M,
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Please use `align` over `eqnarray`. See: http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/

Comment: @Fizunik Please add the example code to the question (with code blocks). Even better create a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You might also like the `fouridx` package, especially if you ever want an index on the left of a large symbol.

Comment: ... or `\sideset` if it is a large operator.

Comment: related: [Superscripts before a letter in math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30554/579)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the command `\prescript` of the `maththools` package.

See the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \prescript{2}{}{K}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```