# How to make a superscript on the upper left hand corner of a letter?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left and right subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript)

How can I make a superscript on the upper left hand corner of a letter?

Comment: dude, don't just mark it as a duplicate. Provide the link to the answer you think is original.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the standard `^` operator; if you require better control, the [leftidx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leftidx) package can be an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{leftidx}

\begin{document}

$ ^{i}A \qquad\leftidx{_1^2}{\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)}{_3^4}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sadly, there's more space between the prescripts and the kernel and the following scripts.  i don't know whether this is a function of the `leftidx` package or something else, but it would be good to look into and "correct".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: you're right. I'll take a look to the implementation of `\leftidx`.

Comment: If `^{i}` is preceded by something else, say, e.g., the operator `+`, you can use `{}` to denote that the superscript is not associated with it: `+ {}^{i}A`

Answer (score 6):

I use the following macro in my documents. I think that I had copied it from c.t.t. and the `mathtools` package also provides a version of this macro.

```
\def\presuper#1#2%
  {\mathop{}%
   \mathopen{\vphantom{#2}}^{#1}%
   \kern-\scriptspace%
   #2}
```