# How can I get to use the sideset command on unusual symbols without an error message

Tags: symbols, errors

I would like to use the command, `$\sideset{_\sigma}{_f}\times$` without an error message. This command renders the way I want it to, (a times with a left subscript of `\sigma`, and a right subscript of f).

My issue however is that I would like to compile through this error without have to skip it. So my question is can I put a command on that line that will compile though just that line, while being able to troubleshoot around it. In particular I would like to skip a particular error. 
If not this, is their some other way I might be able to typeset this.

EDIT

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts, xypic, mathrsfs, graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
$\sideset{_g}{_f}\times$
\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
./test2.tex:7:Limit controlsmust follow a math operator.

< argument > \times \nolimits

                                 _f
1.7 
$\sideset{_\sigma}{_f}\times

                             $
?
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. What is the error message?  We need to know that so that others can try to reproduce the problem and debug it.

Comment: you can use `$\sideset{{}_\sigma}{{}_f}{\mathop{\times}}$` but egreg's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Is the edit that I made the right kind of thing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\sideset` wants as its third argument an operator such as `\sum`; you get what you want by

```
\mathbin{_\sigma\times_f}
```

Comment: See also this summary of solutions [Left and right subscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11566/15925)

Comment: @AndrewSwann Here the "binary operation" nature of `\times` must be preserved, which isn't with `\prescript`.

Comment: I was thinking of two things: (1) the different range of possible commands listed there; (2) the vertical placing in the presence of a superscript on one side but not the other.  It is good to note that any of them can be put inside `\mathbin` to make them into a binary operator, so e.g. one can write `\( a \mathbin{\prescript{}{f}{\times}^N_f} b \)`

Comment: @AndrewSwann The problem is that `\prescript` assumes the presence of a superscript, even if empty; so to get the symbol at the same height on both sides you have to supply an empty superscript: `\prescript{}{\sigma}{\times}^{}_f`. I'd prefer not using `\prescript`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand  wat you want well but the sideset command should be in this format:

```
\sideset{_{left below} ^{left top}} {_{right below} ^{right top}} {a math operator like \sum}
```

Be successful.