# Is there a command to write the form of a combination or permutation?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to write

```
^nP_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}  
\binom nk=^nC_k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
```

but when compiled the n is a little far away from the P and C for my liking. Is there a command to write this? I know there is a `\binom` so  I was hopeful. If not, is there a way to force the n to be closer?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}  
$ ^nP_k=\frac{n!}{(n-k}!} - permutation \\  
\binom nk=^nC_k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} - combination $  
end{document}
```

Comment: ``\binom`` is in package ``amsmath``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript-superscript)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use the `\prescript` command from the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package and define two commands; something along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\Myperm[2][^n]{\prescript{#1\mkern-2.5mu}{}P_{#2}}
\newcommand\Mycomb[2][^n]{\prescript{#1\mkern-0.5mu}{}C_{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Myperm{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\quad
\Mycomb{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\quad
\Myperm[m]{k} = \frac{m!}{(m-k)!}\quad
\Mycomb[m]{k} = \frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}\quad
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not on topic, I've just noticed `\qquad` a few times and wondered what it is?

Comment: @DannyBland `\qquad` introduces (both in text and in math mode) a space equal to twice `\quad`.

Comment: If you want to write `\Myperm{x}{y}` instead of `\Myperm[x]{y}` (different brackets) and are okay not having `n` as the default first parameter, remove`[n]` from both the `\newcommand` lines.

Comment: You might also prefer the `\cramped` style for this, to reduce how much the scripts are raised and lowered.

Comment: I tried using this with the `kaobook` class and am getting the error `LaTeX Error: Command \refeq already defined.` Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 30):

You can define your own:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\Perm}[2]{{}^{#1}\!P_{#2}}%
\newcommand*{\Comb}[2]{{}^{#1}C_{#2}}%

\begin{document}  
$\Perm{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ - permutation 

$\binom nk=\Comb{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ - combination  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

I provide a generic `\permcomb` macro that will be used to setup `\perm` and `\comb`.

The spacing is between the prescript and the following character is kerned with the help of `\mkern`.

The default kerning between the prescript and `P` is `-3mu`, and `-1mu` with `C`, which can be changed by using the optional argument of all three macros.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\permcomb}[4][0mu]{{{}^{#3}\mkern#1#2_{#4}}}
\newcommand*{\perm}[1][-3mu]{\permcomb[#1]{P}}
\newcommand*{\comb}[1][-1mu]{\permcomb[#1]{C}}
\begin{document}
$\perm{n}{k}$

$\comb{n}{k}$

$\permcomb[-3mu]{J}{l}{k}$
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]