# Is there a control like \binom for nPr?

Tags: fontsize

While nPr looks fine with letters, 4P2 looks silly. Is there a dedicated control for nPr and if not, is there a clever way to get a small 4 and 2? I tried \scriptstyle but that affects everything thereafter unless switched off again. But this is very clumsy. I'm using amsmath package.

Comment: `{}_{4}P_{2}` is usual way

Comment: Related Questions: [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542/4301) and [Is there a command to write the form of a combination or permutation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107125/4301) should get you going.

Comment: Thanks to all - I think I'm good. @DavidCarlisle. I couldn't figure a way to trick the first subscript. Shiny. // I'll leave this up for a little while but it looks like this has been asked and answered before so I'll take it down after a while.

Comment: The use of subscripts to get a smaller font in mathmode didn't look right to me either, so here is a solution that works without dropping the numerals below the  line:     Create a new command: : \newcommand{\nPr}[2] {\scriptstyle{#1} \displaystyle{P} \scriptstyle{#2} \displaystyle}.  // I post it because it seems like it might be handy.