# Sup-left with a matrix

Tags: matrices, superscripts

If I want to have supscript on the left, I usually do `{}^xa`. How can I do this when I have a matrix. So what I want is

`{}^x\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}`

However, this doesn't raise the `x` high enough.

I just need this for one application.

Comment: If you are not using it that often you can match the size of the delimiter height and kern it slightly via `{\vphantom{\bigg(}}^x\!\!\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}`

Comment: @percusse: Great. Thanks. I just need to do this one time, so this works well. If you write it as an answer, I will upvote and accept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript-superscript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (an extension package to [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)) provides `\prescript`:

```
\prescript{<left superscript>}{<left subscript>}{<arg>}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \prescript{x}{}{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

In case you need it more frequently, the `tensor` package should solve the problem of height.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}


\[
\tensor*[^x]{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}}{}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option using stacks.  Because it is a lap, one may (or not) wish to add horizontal space prior to the `\tllap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,mathtools}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
  \tllap{\scriptstyle x}
  {\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]