# math mode: subscript in front of variable

Tags: math-mode

Any idea at how I can have a subscript on the left side of a variable?

[image: subscript behind variable]

This is for an agent-based model that requires a little too many indices --- so I thought of trailing the one refer ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I believe that your question is a specific case of this one, which contains a survey of all reasonable ways how to typeset left scripts: [Left and right subscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\prescript` macro provided by `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\begin{document}
   \[
   \prescript{}{5}{\mathit{edu}}_{2,3}= \prescript{}{5}{\mathit{yr}} \prescript{}{5}{\mathit{wg}} + 2
   \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As well, if `edu` is an token, it should probably be `\mathit{edu}`.

Comment: @tohecz Honestly, I have no idea what `edu` is.  So I will change it as you said. :) Thanks.

Comment: @tohecz Why `\mathit{edu}` and not `\textit`? I still don't understand the place for `\mathit` and `\mathrm`.

Comment: @Manuel They are semantic. IMHO, direct usage of `\text??` command in math-mode shows some lack of it (well, `\text??` shouldn't ever be used outside preamble, IMHO). For example, try this semantically correct variant: `\[ \mathrm{e}^{x} = 1 \quad\text{if and \emph{only if}}\quad x = 0\]` versus: `\[ \textrm{e}^{x} \quad\textrm{if and }\textit{only if}\quad x = 0 \]`. The result is very likely the same, unless you are inside `{theorem}` for instance, but the semantics are lost. Of course, even better would be having a macro for the constant if you use it more than once or twice.

Comment: The one problem I see is the prescript is set at a different vertical height than the regular subscripts.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That is how it is in the picture provided by OP!

Comment: I hadn't noticed that before.  Good point.

Comment: @tohecz Well, *there* `\mathrm{e}` is what you want, a math upright to identify some letters. But in case of a subscript, or in this case, I still don't see the place for `\mathit` or `\mathrm` (in fact, if I were to choose, I think I would go for `\text··`). I just want to make up my mind; but I think it's not solved the place for those “alphabets”.

Comment: @Manuel Think of it this way: If it should be italic in theorem statement, then it's text. Otherwise it's math. (Last comment from me here to avoid off-topic chatter here, we can continue [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).)

Comment: @tohecz No discussion, since I don't have an opinion, but that's a good and nice one idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

   \[
   \sideset{_5}{_{2,3}}{\mathop{edu}}= \sideset{_5}{}{\mathop{yr}} \sideset{_5}{}{\mathop{wg}} + 2
   \]
   \[ \sideset{_{ll}^{ul}}{_{lr}^{ur}}\prod \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Herbert, I will select Harish's answer, but thank you and @tohecz for your replies as well. I did not realized this had been answered before... Thank you!

Comment: As explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript, this is an abuse of `\sideset`. That is as well clear from the fact that you need explicit `\mathop` to make it work.