# Aligning Mortality Two-sided Subscripts

Tags: subscripts

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
${}_{10}q^{1}_{30:40} = 0.17$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way I can align the subscripts on the left and right sides? The 1 should be on top of the 30, as displayed above.

Comment: Does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/89851/1181665 help?

Comment: @mbork - I know of that information; thank you though

Comment: a nice answer here: [math mode: subscript in front of variable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216306/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\prescript{<sup>}{<sub>}` from `mathtools` (which loads/extends `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\prescript{}{10}q^{1}_{30:40} = 0.17$
\end{document}
```

The problem with your code is that `q` has both a superscript and a subscript, so its subscript is placed differently than the subscript (with no superscript) on the empty atom `{}`.

[image]

Comment: Very, very nice. Thank you - will give you best answer as soon as the site lets me...