# Pullback symbol of morphisms?

Tags: symbols

How can I get something like this:

[image]

which was meant to be the symbol for the pullback by the morphisms `$s$` and `$t$`.

It is meant to be used inline in math mode. It should be like x which we get by using `\times`.

My first effort was `_{s} \times_t` but there was much space between the `$s$` and the `\times`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any limitations with this request? Do you want to use it in inline text and/or math, or just as a graphic? If you want inline usage, how would this affect the line-height? If used in inline math, will this be used in powers as well (and therefore need to size based on usage/location? Is the size of the cross the same as that of an X? Please be *specific* in your request.

Comment: I added some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542/5764), I'd suggest

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pullback}[2]{{}_{#1}\kern-\scriptspace{\times}_{#2}}

\begin{document}

See $\pullback{s}{t}$ and then some \ldots

\end{document}
```

Using `{\times}` removes the spacing around `\times`, thereby changing it from an operator to an ordinary symbol. Minor spacing adjustment around scripted symbols provides the desired layout.

Comment: The s and t are not equally spaced and it does not look nice when you write something before and after it, the spacing gets messed up. Anyway, I appreciate your help.

Comment: `{}_{#1}\kern-\scriptspace{\times}_{#2}`

Comment: And, looking more closely to the question, you should add `\mathbin` around the thing.

Comment: @Dion: Will the symbol be used as an operator between two other elements?

Comment: Now it seems nice =) Yep, I want to write things like $A s_\times_t B$..

Comment: @Dion: Then you may be interested in `\newcommand{\pullback}[2]{\mathbin{...}}`.