# Small index left to the left bracket

Tags: amsmath, underscore

[image]

I want to know how to make the underscore "3" placed to the left of the left bracket. Also, in the image it is quite far away. How to make it closer? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See if in answers to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript you find something useful for you.