# Does Tex, LaTeX support 'Tetration' & 'super square root' notations?

Tags: symbols

I would like to ask how can I use Tetration notations in this page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

in TeX, LaTeX

It seems to me it does not support Tetration symbols??

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Erh, all those images on the wiki page is made using latex. Please provide information about what you have done so far to conclude that it should not be supported

Comment: `leftidx`,`mathtools` and `tensor` packages offer macros for this purpose.

Comment: The wikipedia article you quote uses TeX notation (inside <math> tags), you can just copy it from there (use the "edit" tab in wikipedia to see the source code of the page).

Answer (score 5):

Latex does indeed support Tetration notation. Simply use:

```
{^{n}a}
```

This produces the notation. This should not require the use of any special packages.

Comment: ${^{n}a}$ for Tetration & ${\sqrt{x}_{s}}$ for Super Square RooT , thank you so much.