# How to write Arabic subscript in XeLaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, circuitikz

I mean like in English such as in `V_s`

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}[american]
 \draw (0,0) to[V,v=$V_s$,invert] (0,2);
 \end{circuitikz}
 \end{document}
```

I mean the letter and the subscript of it are both in Arabic.

Comment: Is your question somehow speicifc to `circuittikz`, or why is it included in your MWE?

Comment: No, it is general not limited to this example.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: Khaled Hosny’s Libertinus family includes Libertinus Math (which covers Arabic mathematical symbols), and complements his Amiri font well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two problems there

1. the need to type in two scripts at once, which is not really a problem with XeLaTeX
2. the need to typeset a math-version of the arabic font, which can be circumvented by simply using `amsmath`'s `\text{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%pick a font that has knows arabic
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\def\matharabic#1{\ensuremath{\text{\begin{Arabic}#1‎\end{Arabic}}}}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}[american]
 \draw (0,0) to[V,v=${}_\matharabic{عَفْواً}\matharabic{شُكْراً}_\matharabic{عَفْواً}$,invert] (0,2);
 \end{circuitikz}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean Arabic-Arabic subscript. Can that be done ?

Comment: The first time that my eyes see a arabic text near the tension :-). Very good your answer.

Comment: I mean instead of using V using Arabic letter.

Comment: Can you make it on the left(I mean the subscript )?

Comment: maybe this helps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript-superscript