# How do I LaTeX this?

Tags: symbols

[image: How can I LaTeX this notation which denotes the collection of functions from set X to set Y?]

How can I LaTeX this notation which denotes the collection of functions from set X to set Y?

Comment: 'ello! Perhaps this thread can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript-superscript

Comment: $Y_X$? Or some more clarity is needed about what you want.

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev not clear from the image but the X is on the baseline so more `${}^Y X$`

Comment: @David Carlisle, now I see and agree with you. Up-voted. Maybe $\!{}^YX$ to ensure left interval, but it all depends on the context.