# Place Integral parameters to the left of the Integral symbol?

Tags: integral

I am trying to draw an Integral where the parameter of the integral is to the left of the integral sign as it is here:
[image: My desired Integral]

However, I have found nothing online for how to achieve this. Is there a (preferably easy) way to set the Integration parameter to the left of the symbol?

Comment: Maybe `\sideset` from amsmath, but it is a bit strange notation.

Comment: @mickep That does work, but the distance is a little too large. Is there a way to make the side-symbols closer to the center of the wrapped symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For single letter in the left superscript, you can use `\prescript` and `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` package. For multi characters, try `leftindex` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % can be deleted since leftindex preloads mathtools
\usepackage{fixdif} % for \d
\usepackage{leftindex}
\begin{document}
\[
  \prescript{\mathrlap{\gamma}}{}{\int} f \d x \quad
  \prescript{\partial V}{}{\int} f \d x \quad
  \leftindex^{\partial V} {\int} f \d x \quad
  \leftindex^\gamma {\int} f \d x \quad
  \leftindex^{\alpha\beta\gamma\partial V} {\int} f \d x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information about left and right scripts, have a look at this post [Left and right subscript / superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript-superscript)

Comment: That works well for single symbols, but as soon as I use more than one (something like $\partial V$), it overlaps the Integral symbol.

Comment: That's true. The solution above is for single symbol. What's the maximum length of the contents in left superscript for your use case? @lan

Comment: In my case, the maximum length would be two. I think leftindex looks good, so I accepted your answer. Thank your for helping :)