# Vector Notation Latex

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, vector, mathematics, scientific-notation

Does someone know how can I write this type of notation in Latex?[image: Notation]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe similar to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11542/47927

Comment: Are you doing chemistry?

Comment: @JasperHabicht, Exactly like this, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @egreg, I'm working with vectors, specifically in Robotics.