# How to change the side on which the superscript appears?

Tags: superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left and right subscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/left-and-right-subscript)
>   [Superscripts before a letter in math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30554/superscripts-before-a-letter-in-math)

I need to write something almost identical to this notation `$P_{O}^A$`except I need the superscript A not to be on the right with the subscript O but to be on the left side?

Is this possible which commands/packages I need to use?

Comment: How about: `$^AP_O$`?

Comment: Thanks count Zero that does the trick,can I set your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: This is a duplicate; just vote up his answer in the thread he linked to.

Comment: searching my (inclomplete) package database, i find fouridx, leftidx, subdepth, subsupscripts, tensind and tensor
listed in this area. i've never tried any of them, but if david's suggestion doesn't help, perhaps one of those might help. (fouridx seems suited, for example).

Comment: In addition to the two that are listed as possible duplicated, there's also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334/86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amsmath` has a `\sideset` command that allows the placing of subscripts at various points.