# Aligning left sub- and superscripts to the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am using a self defined command to typeset isotopes with charges. It is as follows:

```
\newcommand{\elem}[3]{\ensuremath{{\vphantom{#2}}#1\mathrm{#2}#3}}
```

Example:

```
\elem{^{16}_{8}}{O}{^{2-}_{2}}
```

What I would like to achieve, is that the sub- and superscript on the left side are aligned to the O. The right sub- and superscript are of course aligned to the O by default.
Does anyone have a (preferrably simple) solution?

Comment: I think there are already exists packages for this maybe something like [LaTeX/Chemical Graphics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Chemical_Graphics) would be helpful.

Comment: see [non-kludgey left subscripts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407/579) regarding the `tensor` package.  (maybe not duplicate, but the answer for someone not dealing with chemical notation.)

Comment: I just realized that the \ce-command from mhchem not also is capable of doing what I want, but also sets the charge a bit to the right, which I did not think of before but I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following code:

```
\def\elem#1#2#3#4#5{{%
   \phantom{{}^{#2}_{#3}}% space for left indexes
   {\vphantom{\rm#1}}^{\llapscr{#2}}_{\llapscr{#3}}% llaped left indexes
   {\rm#1}^{#4}_{#5}% base + right indexes
}}
\def\llapscr#1{\llap{$\scriptstyle#1$}}

Test: $ \elem O {16}{8}{2-}{2} $

\bye
```

Comment: This code works perfectly. As written in the comment above, mhchem also sets the charge a bit more to the right, which is good. But as I did not think of this before asking, so it was not part of the question, I accepted your answer nevertheless. Thank you.